# Automated JQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this slideshow using javascript and JQuery. I want to use it multiple times on a webpage. I can get both to appear, but only one will cycle through all the pictures and then start over again. The second one only cycles through and then ends. Can someone help me with the code? I want all slideshows on the webpage to continually cycle. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

</style>

</head>

<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="ocean.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
    <img src="ocean2.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <img src="ocean3.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
</div>

<br />

<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="flower.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
    <img src="flower2.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <img src="flower3.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try making div ids unique. You can use same class for both of them.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? I kind of understand, but I tried playing around with it and couldn't get anything to work. Do I need to change the div id="slideshow" name? If so, what else do I need to change above in the css and query sections?

Answer (score 0):

you could generate a unique ID for each instance of the slideshow, because your `$('#slideshow IMG.active');` stuff picks up the multiple instances you have. try something like this partial:

```
function slideShow(element_of_slideshow){
    var now = new Date().getTime(), uid = "ss" + now;
    $(element_of_slideshow).attr("id",uid);

   // then call it like this in the function
   $("#"+uid+" IMG.active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `id` attributes in html tags are supposed to be unique on a page.

therefore your selector: `$('#slideshow IMG:last')` will find the last img tag in the **first** occurence of a tag with the id #slideshow.

Maybe consider using the [jquery plugin pattern](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).